# how to Filter each column of the table together

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-core

I have a table of inputs to edit all people and I want to search in each column and only the searched content will be displayed in the row.But it doesn't work.Please see the picture.

I have a table of inputs to edit all people and I want to search in each column and only the searched content will be displayed in the row.But it doesn't work.Please see the picture

```
<script>
    function myfunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtvalue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            if (td) {
                txtvalue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }

            }
        }

    }

</script>

<script>
    function myfunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtvalue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("someTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[2];
            if (td) {
                txtvalue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > 1) {

                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

```
                    <td><input class="" autocomplete="off" type="text" style="width: 110px" name="[@i].FatherName" value="@Model.ToList()[i].FatherName" /></td>
                    <td><input class="" autocomplete="off" type="text" style="width: 110px" name="[@i].PersonSryalPoshtCartMlie" value="@Model.ToList()[i].PersonSryalPoshtCartMlie" /></td>

            <td>
                <input class="" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="myInput" placeholder="جستجو ..." />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="myInput2" placeholder="جستجو ..." />

            </td>
```

[image]

Comment: First, writing the same message or code multiple times does not help, second it would be better if you used the snippet tool <> to create a working example of your code

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

In the example I built, the search box with `id="myInput"` searches for values of type `<td>value</td>`, so use `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`. The search box with `id="myInput2"` searches for values of type `<td><input value=xxx /></td>`, so use `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];`.

In your picture, it seems that `<input />` is used. In this case, the corresponding value cannot be obtained by using `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]`. If your first column is of type `<td>value</td>` and the second column is of type `<td><input value=xxx /></td>`, then you can use `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]` when searching for the first column , you need to use `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` when searching the second column.

Pay attention to the index value, the first column index using `<input />` is `0`.

---

You are confusing jQuery and javascript. To get the `tr` in the `table` should be `document.getElementsByTagName("tr")`, `document.getElementsByClassName("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")` is wrong.

According to your picture, your `for` loop should start from the third row, which is `i=2`, otherwise the title line and search line will be hidden.

And you can pass this into myfunction(), and then get its id for judgment, without writing a lot of repetitive code.

I made a simple example, you can refer to it.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="myfunction(this)" id="myInput" placeholder="جستجو ..." /></td>
            <td><input class="" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="myfunction(this)" id="myInput2" placeholder="جستجو ..." /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td><input value="Des1" /></td>
            <td><input value="AAA" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td><input value="Des2" /></td>
            <td><input value="BBB" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name3</td>
            <td><input value="Des3" /></td>
            <td><input value="CCC" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name4</td>
            <td><input value="Des4" /></td>
            <td><input value="DDD" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name5</td>
            <td><input value="Des5" /></td>
            <td><input value="EEE" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name6</td>
            <td><input value="Des6" /></td>
            <td><input value="FFF" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script>
    function myfunction(el) {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtvalue;
        input = el;
        var Id = el.id;
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (Id == "myInput") {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            }
            else
            {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
            }
            
            if (td) {
                txtvalue = td.textContent || td.innerText || td.value;
                if (txtvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }

            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]

[image]

In addition, you can check for error messages and step-by-step debugging in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: This code works correctly for the first td tag, but if I want to search for the second td tag, it is not possible. I changed the code like this, but it does not work.

Comment: td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

Comment: Hi @sadegh, Yes, the index starts from 0, you need to provide the corresponding index value to retrieve the corresponding column.

Comment: Yes, I changed the value but it didn't work. Please test and edit the answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @sadegh, I updated my answer. Please check if you are in the situation I describe. If not, please provide the corresponding code.